# Encode nested object as a string

Tags: json, scala, circe

Given the following case classes:

```scala
case class Mailbox(value: String)
case class Group(objectType: String, mailbox: Mailbox)
```

I am attempting to find a way to encode a Group object as follows where `mailbox` is encoded as a string value, rather than an object:

```json
{
  "objectType" : "Group",
  "mailbox" : "mailto:info@example.com"
}
```

With automatic derivation, encoding/decoding both succeed but I end up with a result like the following as would be expected:

```json
{
  "objectType" : "Group",
  "mailbox" : {
    "value" : "mailto:info@example.com"
  }
}
```

I can achieve the result that I want by adding a custom encoder like the following:

```scala
object Mailbox {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Mailbox] = (m: Mailbox) => Json.fromString(m.value)
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Mailbox] = deriveDecoder[Mailbox]
}
```

However, then decoding fails with the following:

```
DecodingFailure(Attempt to decode value on failed cursor, List(DownField(value), DownField(mailbox)))
```

I've attempted to resolve this by also writing a custom decoder for Mailbox but get the same result. Any guidance on the correct way to approach this situation would be appreciated.

Here is the complete code:

```scala
case class Mailbox(value: String)
object Mailbox {
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Mailbox] = (m: Mailbox) => Json.fromString(m.value)
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Mailbox] = deriveDecoder[Mailbox]
}

case class Group(objectType: String, mailbox: Mailbox)

object Sandbox {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val group: Group = Group("Group", Mailbox("mailto:info@example.com"))
    val json: String = group.asJson.spaces2
    println(json)

    parser.decode[Group](json) match {
      case Right(group) => println(group)
      case Left(err) => println(err)
    }
  }
}
```

*Note that this is a derived example, meant only to demonstrate my question.*

Comment: If you make that class a **value class** and use `circe-generic-extras` it would work out of the box. But, note that using **Value classes** may cause performance issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` / `contramap` instead to map your type to String and back:

```
object Mailbox {

  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Mailbox] = Encoder.encodeString.contramap[Mailbox](_.value)
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Mailbox] = Decoder.decodeString.map[Mailbox](Mailbox.apply)
}
```

A documentation describing almost exactly this scenario is at [Custom encoders/decoders](https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/custom-codecs.html)

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative for creating custom encoders/decoders, you could also use `deriveUnwrappedEncoder/deriveUnwrappedDecoder` from circe extras.

Just add following import in you `buid.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "io.circe" %% "circe-generic-extras" % "xxx"
```

and then you will be able to do:

```
import io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto._

implicit val encoder: Encoder[Mailbox] = deriveUnwrappedEncoder
implicit val decoder: Decoder[Mailbox] = deriveUnwrappedDecoder
```